# .NET Timer does not callback when machine is high on resource utilization

Tags: c#, timer

I am using the `System.Timers.Timer` for callback after every few seconds.
The callback basically sends the continuous heartbeat messages to connected server.

If heartbeat messages are not send for n seconds then, server disconnects it from connected client.

What I observed that when user machine is very high on resource utilization like - 100% CPU utilization and almost 95% of Memory utilization and system is not responding to user interactions, then Timer callback does not get invoked.

I also tried with `System.Threading.Timer` but no luck, getting same result.

What is the best way in .NET to make sure your action invokes irrespective of the machine resource utilization.

Note,

- This implementations works just perfect under normal scenarios.
- I am not using the UI threads from my windows application to invoke the callback, it using background (non-UI) thread.

Comment: When machine is at 100% CPU utilization there is no more CPU available to run your timer task. All the applications are fighting for processor time, and within your app the timer-triggered action is fighting with all the other stuff (UI thread and other background threads). It's normal that the timer thread might not be a winner here.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I have another small Java Applet, it still gets attention from the CPU and it does sends the heartbeats to server, I am wondering why not .NET application? Will it help if I go native code (C++). ?

Comment: It might be that `Timer` gets really low priority. I don't think there is a way to set it.

Comment: Can you use a Windows Forms Timer? It executes on UI thread and might get higher priority.

Comment: If the machine is so badly overloaded that is it trashing the paging file and user input is no longer responsive then to odds for getting a timely Elapsed event handler start to drop quickly as well.  The server drew the correct conclusion, the machine in fact *is* no longer capable of providing an adequate service guarantee.  You'll have to limit its workload or buy more RAM.

Comment: Windows Forms Timer did not help. Btw, the machine is quiet high on configuration (8GB RAM).

Comment: The machine is painfully overloaded. Even if you can hack around it by increasing the priority of your process, it is not a reasonable solution. You risk instability. Not worth it.

Comment: I assume the client is sending other messages to the server as well, not just heartbeats. The server should treat another message as evidence that the client is alive as well, not just heartbeats. That prevents the server from thinking the client is dead, even if it is still receiving messages. In that scenario, the heartbeat being lower priority and dropping messages is a good thing. Also, make sure that the heartbeat frequency is low enough, to prevent the heartbeats from generating significant load on the system themselves.

Comment: Primarily messages flows (initiated) from the server, subsequently processed by the clients. Yeah, I guess increasing the Heartbeat frequency time is the only option. But this would not going to solve the issue, considering system hangs for a minutes or more.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your periodic heartbeat is something very critical for your application, may be even more important than UI responsiveness and other issues.
In such cases in real-time systems usually create a dedicated thread for that with high priority.
So, try creating a dedicated thread (not BackgroundWorker but new System.Threading.Thread), give it high priority (ThreadPriority.Highest) and send the heartbeats from this priority thread.

Comment: This has reduced number of times it fails to send the heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "What is the best way in .NET to make sure your action invokes irrespective of the machine resource utilization." depends on your definition of "irrespective".

This question lies in the realm of Real Time Computing.

If you endeavour to use C# on windows, I'm afraid the closest you can get to your goal is to put a Thread on "Real Time" priority and then use a SpinWait between calls. The result would be that your thread would take up 100% utilitization of a single core.

Even then there are timing issues you might have issues with.

You might want to take a look at using an Real Time OS and program in C++.

However both of these solutions are extremely expensive.

I would suggest however that you should fix the real heart of the issue, which is that your application is clearly using Threads inefficiently. You may want to rewrite your entire application with asynchronous I/O, which should reduce the CPU utilization.

You can also try to scale your application out horizontally. But it is clear your system has outgrown the box.

Answer (score 1):

The final approach which I went for is -

- Improve the ping frequency (heartbeat) duration from existing n seconds to 3 * n seconds.
- Send the ping message from high priority thread.

I have to admit that this still does not fix the issue, but just tries to delay the failure.